# Python Socket Message Exchange

Tags: python, sockets

I have to edit this code i have in python of a chatServer so that you can send private messages to a receiver and if the recevier isnt logged in it outputs an error to the sender. Also any message sent by the server to the client must be provided with the name of the original sender.

### chatClient.py

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import threading
from datetime import datetime

PORT = 8888
HEADER_LENGTH = 2


def receive_fixed_length_msg(sock, msglen):
    message = b''
    while len(message) < msglen:
        chunk = sock.recv(msglen - len(message))
        if chunk == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        message = message + chunk
    return message


def receive_message(sock):
    header = receive_fixed_length_msg(sock, HEADER_LENGTH)
    message_length = struct.unpack("!H", header)[0] 

    message = None
    if message_length > 0: 
        message = receive_fixed_length_msg(sock, message_length) 
        message = message.decode("utf-8")

    return message


def send_message(sock, message):
    encoded_message = message.encode("utf-8") 
    header = struct.pack("!H", len(encoded_message))

    message = header + encoded_message 
    sock.sendall(message);

def message_receiver():
    while True:
        msg_received = receive_message(sock)
        if len(msg_received) > 0:  # ce obstaja sporocilo
            current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            print("[RKchat][" + current_time + "] " + name + ": " + msg_received)

print("[system] connecting to chat server ...")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("localhost", PORT))
print("[system] connected!")

thread = threading.Thread(target=message_receiver)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

name = input("Vpiši ime: ")

while True:
    try:
        msg_send = input("")
        send_message(sock, msg_send)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

### chatServer.py

```
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
import socket
import struct
import threading

PORT = 8888
HEADER_LENGTH = 2


def receive_fixed_length_msg(sock, msglen):
    message = b''
    while len(message) < msglen:
        chunk = sock.recv(msglen - len(message)) 
        if chunk == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        message = message + chunk  # pripni prebrane bajte sporocilu

    return message


def receive_message(sock):
    header = receive_fixed_length_msg(sock, HEADER_LENGTH)
    message_length = struct.unpack("!H", header)[0]

    message = None
    if message_length > 0:
        message = receive_fixed_length_msg(sock, message_length)
        message = message.decode("utf-8")

    return message


def send_message(sock, message):
    encoded_message = message.encode("utf-8")

    header = struct.pack("!H", len(encoded_message))

    message = header + encoded_message
    sock.sendall(message);

def client_thread(client_sock, client_addr):
    global clients

    print("[system] connected with " + client_addr[0] + ":" + str(client_addr[1]))
    print("[system] we now have " + str(len(clients)) + " clients")

    try:
        while True:
            msg_received = receive_message(client_sock)

            if not msg_received: 
                break

            print("[RKchat] [" + client_addr[0] + ":" + str(client_addr[1]) + "] : " + msg_received)

            for client in clients:
                send_message(client, msg_received.upper())
    except:
        pass

    with clients_lock:
        clients.remove(client_sock)
    print("[system] we now have " + str(len(clients)) + " clients")
    client_sock.close()

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("localhost", PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)

print("[system] listening ...")
clients = set()
clients_lock = threading.Lock()
while True:
    try:
        client_sock, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
        with clients_lock:
            clients.add(client_sock)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=client_thread, args=(client_sock, client_addr));
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

print("[system] closing server socket ...")
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: Then you probably need to write some code to do that. Stackoverflow is not for others to write code for you. If you have a specific problem with this, please explain what it is and someone might be able to help you. As your question is now formatted, it is unlikely to receive any helpful responses.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know what to do...i was hoping to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have now a simple "receive a message, broadcast it to all" type client and server.  As written in comments, we do not write code for you, but here are a couple of ideas you might be able to use.

First, you need to build a protocol. Now you treat everything the server receives as a message and broadcast it to other connections. If  you now need to cater for public (broadcast to all) and private messages (send only to a certain user), the server needs to know usernames. The server needs to also distinguish between public and private messages.

For example, you could require in your server that the first message you receive from a new connection would be

```
REGISTER username
```

You would then recognise this message, and instead of having a set for clients, you would change this to a dictionary and have the username as the key

```
clients[username] = client_sock
```

or something like that.

when your client threads receive a message, they parse it as well. Possible messages could be

```
PUBLICMESSAGE message
PRIVATEMESSAGE username message
```

If you receive a public message, you would do what you do now. If you receive a privatemessage, you would get the socket where to send in

```
try:
     client = clients[username]
     send_message(client, message)
except KeyError:
     Send an error message back stating the target user is not online
```

These are just pointers. You need a protocol, because you need to distinguish between public and private messages, and you need means to let the server know what is your username, so that it can use it as an identifier. Then you need to build a little bit of parsing to separate protocol keywords from messages.

I would also like to point you to a previous answer I wrote some time ago.  [Python: Multithreaded socket server runs endlessly when client stops unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850472/python-multithreaded-socket-server-runs-endlessly-when-client-stops-unexpectedl/49873909#49873909)  Please read the last paragraphs starting from "TCP sockets transmit data, not messages".  Now your server does not cater for scenarios 3-5 but it should. This becomes more important when you build a protocol, as you will go wrong in so many ways if you receive more from your socket than you intended, as you would be swallowing the consecutive protocol keywords.